# What are the lines of triangles on the DCA RWY 19 River Visual approach chart?

Tags: faa, aeronautical-charts, visual-approaches

A recent update of a certain flight simulator made me revisit this chart and I had not noticed the lines of triangles (at the Chain Bridge / Roosevelt Bridge etc, but not at the Key Bridge) in a past version, years ago.
[image]
What are they?  I couldn't find the information in the FAA Chart User's Guide.

Answer (score 4):

So, applying some local knowledge, the [Key Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_Bridge_(Washington,_D.C.)) is a high arch bridge in that it is a good distance above the water level, and the other ones listed, [Rochambeau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/14th_Street_bridges), [Memorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arlington_Memorial_Bridge) , [Roosevelt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Roosevelt_Bridge), and [Chain Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_Bridge_(Potomac_River)) are all "low" bridges, more like causeways.

I tried looking for a chart legend that said this, but I wasn't able to find one.

Answer (score 0):

They represent the bridges. You can use the bridges to gauge where to be on your approach.

Comment: As the Q notes, the Key Bridge doesn’t have them. What’s different about the bridges that do?